# can't ping my instance private IP from other instance in the same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two instances and both of them are on same subnet and same VPC, one of the instances is openvpn when I'm connected to VPN and try to ping the other instance (10.x.x.x) I dont get response although it is reachable through the public IP address.

I enabled all traffic for all sources on both security groups and Network ACLs for both instances.

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: To be able to answer this question accurately we would need to see the actual configuration of your VPC, security groups, and network ACLs. From what you've written, all we can do is guess that "all traffic" doesn't include ICMP.

Comment: Does the subnet routing table routes internal traffic (within subnet) correctly?

Comment: @helloV VPC (afaik) won't let you configure the route tables in any way that will break the routing for destination addresses within the VPC supernet.  The "local" route is sort of sacrosanct.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you are correct. Verified it just now. Thanks.

Comment: @kdgregory  I enabled ICMP traffic, still not working, I cant RDP the instance either, it is like the two instances can't see each other through private IPs

Comment: So you need to edit your question with all of the details of your VPC config, just like I said two days ago.

Comment: When you say "it is reachable through the public IP address", do you mean you can ping its public IP? Also, I would recommend not messing with the default network ACLs unless you really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue.
Modifying the security group with an additional inbound rule of "ALL ICMP" fixed it to me.
Custom ICMP with echo reply, is not sufficient.  You have to go with ALL ICMP.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue but adding the `ALL ICMP` Inbound Rule to the Security Group of both `OpenVPN server` and `Private server` has resolved the issue and now the packet loss is not happening like before. You can refer to the screenshot attached.[image: Inbound Rule Security Group]